# Javascript how to randomly select a specific amount of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

I have created a function that returns the login names of random users located on the following api website(https://api.github.com/users)

```
<script>
fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(function(response) {
 
    response.json().then(function(users){
    document.write("Highlighred Github users")
    users.forEach(function(user){ 

for (let i=0; i< 8; i++) {
   document.write('<br>')
   document.write((users[Math.floor(Math.random() *users.length)].login))
}
    });
  });
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
</script>
```

Currently it does return random login names from that file, however, I wish to only randomly select 8 users from this list. My attempt at doing so can be seen in the for loop `i < 8` however it prints alot more than 8(240 to be exact)

How can I have it so just returns 8 randomly? say for example

```
ezmobius
mojodna
kevwil
wayneeseguin
railsjitsu
bmizerany
atmos
fanvsfan
```

Comment: At a guess... you have 30 users?  (or the API is returning the first 30?) Do you see a correlation between 30, 8 and 240?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, remove useless loop, i have commented out `users.forEach(function(user){`

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/users').then(function(response) {
 
    response.json().then(function(users){
    document.write("Highlighred Github users")
//     users.forEach(function(user){ 

for (let i=0; i< 8; i++) {
   document.write('<br>')
   document.write((users[Math.floor(Math.random() *users.length)].login))
}
    });
//   });
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```